# Access annotated property in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I’ve searched around for this but found no information at all. Say I create a property like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) NSString *someString __attribute((annotate(“Try to access this text?)));
```

How could I access the text in the annotation part of the property? I’m guessing I’d have to utilize Objective-c runtime but I found no information there either.

Comment: Please explain why you wish to do this and under what context - so  I can help illicit the right answer.

Comment: I was thinking of creating a macro for the annotation and naming it “REQUIRED”, which I can then use to make required properties in models for object mapping. For instance, let’s say I map values from a dictionary, I was thinking that I would loop through all properties with the “REQUIRED” annotation and check if they were mapped successfully.

Comment: Use the KVC feature refer to the [JSONModel](https://github.com/jsonmodel/jsonmodel).

Comment: You are correct, however it could be a module written in objective-c in a project that now uses swift as is common. Quite frankly converting these types of things pays off the effort of shoe-horning new code into objective-c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, sales pitch - swift would make this easily transparent with optionals. Since you are using objective-c here's how I would do it:

```
@interface SomeModel {
static NSString * const _requiredProperties[] = {
        [0] = @"first",
        [1] = @"second"
    };
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *first;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *second;

@end



-(BOOL) doLoad:(...) {
    //map properties here
    Bool success = YES;
    foreach(NSString property in _requiredProperties {
        success &= ([self valueForKey: property] != nil);
    }
return success;
}
```

The objective-C language doesn't contain the types of constructs you need. Keep it simple, handle missing properties elegantly.

Also if it's JSON, there's plenty of frameworks available to help. Unsure of your mapping here.

Alternatively you can query the protocol, and use the fact it is in a protocol to determine if required.

See this hello world like example that prints out the protocols in the required protocol - sadly the third param which is "YES" for required seems to include optionals for me on OSX. So I made a separate protocol for optionals. This might help you.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <objc/runtime.h>

@protocol TestProtocolRequired
@required
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;
@end

@protocol TestProtocolExtended
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *address;

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        unsigned int outCount, i;
        objc_property_t *properties = protocol_copyPropertyList2(@protocol(TestProtocolRequired), &outCount, YES, YES);
        for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
            objc_property_t property = properties[i];
            fprintf(stdout, "%s %s\n", property_getName(property), property_getAttributes(property));
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

It prints out

```
firstName T@"NSString",&,N
lastName T@"NSString",&,N
```

Comment: Thanks, looks very clean. I’ve been meaning to look into Swift but haven’t had the time to dive deep. For the sake of the question, is it possible to loop through properties and check their annotation flag?

Comment: It doesn’t support it. __attribute is compiler only and cannot be retrieved. It offers hints to the compiler. Your other option is to use protocol required and optional but I’m not sure you can loop over the properties

Comment: Thank you for your expertise, Mitchell!

Comment: Could you think of any way it would be possible to create a macro that could flag properties as required? Just wondering

Comment: To be honest, I cannot think of one that isn't a large hack - maybe overriding the setter. Let me add an alternate idea to the answer though.